# How can I get rid of this memory leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, scheduling

I have been trying to implement a Highest Response Ratio Next Scheduling Program (code underneath) in C. The code is also working in itself. My only Problem is, that I have a memory leak which I cant/ don't know how to get rid of.

I am quite new to C, so help would be appreciated.

In `HRRN_new_arrival` I add a new process to the queue, for which I allocate memory. However, I have no idea how to actually free that allocated memory. For everything that I have tried (and I tried a lot) I either had double freed mem or memory leak.
I would very much appreciate it if someone could maybe try and explain to me what the problem is how it could be solved and how i could fix my code to get rid of this memory leak.

(Quick Overview of how my code works):
In HRRN_startup a new queue is created, where the processes are going to be stored in.
In `HRRN_new_arrival` a new `HRRN` process is being allocated and added to the queue.
In `HRRN_tick`:

I first check if either the running process which is an argument is either 0 or if it finished running. If true, I remove that element from the queue. Then I go over each element of the queue, update the response ratio and check for the max response ratio. Then I set running process to the max rr ratio. Later I increase the waiting time of each process by 1 and return the running process if there is one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static queue_object *HRRN_queue;

process *HRRN_tick(process *running_process)
{
    if (running_process == NULL || (running_process != NULL && running_process->time_left == 0))
    {
        if (running_process != NULL && running_process->time_left == 0)
        {
            queue_object *prev = HRRN_queue;
            queue_object *temp = HRRN_queue->next != NULL ? HRRN_queue->next : NULL;
            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                return NULL;
            }
            while (((HRRN_process *)temp->object)->this_process != running_process)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
                prev = prev->next;
            }
            prev->next = temp->next;
            free((HRRN_process *)temp);

            running_process = NULL;
        }

        queue_object *temp_process = HRRN_queue->next;
        HRRN_process *max_rr_process = NULL;
        while (temp_process != NULL)
        {
            HRRN_process *temp_process_HRRN = (HRRN_process *)temp_process->object;
            if (temp_process_HRRN->this_process->time_left != 0)
            {
                temp_process_HRRN->rr = ((temp_process_HRRN->waiting_time + temp_process_HRRN->this_process->time_left) / (float)temp_process_HRRN->this_process->time_left);
                if (max_rr_process == NULL || temp_process_HRRN->rr >= max_rr_process->rr)
                {
                    max_rr_process = temp_process_HRRN;
                }
            }
            temp_process = temp_process->next;
        }

        if (max_rr_process != NULL)
        {
            running_process = max_rr_process->this_process;
        }
    }

    // increment the waiting time for the other processes
    queue_object *temp = HRRN_queue->next;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        HRRN_process *temp_process_HRRN = (HRRN_process *)temp->object;
        if (temp_process_HRRN->this_process != running_process)
        {
            temp_process_HRRN->waiting_time++;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if (running_process != NULL)
    {
        running_process->time_left--;
    }

    return running_process;
}

int HRRN_startup()
{
    HRRN_queue = new_queue();
    if (HRRN_queue == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

process *HRRN_new_arrival(process *arriving_process, process *running_process)
{
    if (arriving_process != NULL)
    {
        HRRN_process *to_be_added = calloc(1, sizeof(HRRN_process));
        to_be_added->this_process = arriving_process;
        to_be_added->rr = 1;
        to_be_added->waiting_time = 0;
        queue_add(to_be_added, HRRN_queue);
    }
    return running_process;
}

void HRRN_finish()
{
    free_queue(HRRN_queue);
}
```

```
void free_queue(queue_object *queue)
{
    queue_object *to_delete = queue;
    if (queue == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    queue_object *temp = queue->next;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        free(to_delete);
        to_delete = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    free(to_delete);
}
```

```
typedef struct _process{
    unsigned int start_time;
    unsigned int time_left;
    unsigned int priority;
    char id;
}process;

typedef struct _queue_object{
    void* object;
    struct _queue_object* next;
}queue_object;

typedef struct _HRRN_process{
    process* this_process;
    int waiting_time;
    float rr;
}HRRN_process;
```

Comment: If you are using gcc or clang, add the compiler options `-fsanitize=address,undefined,leak` and it may be able to tell you what allocatations you leak at runtime

Comment: Please provide a [mre] i.e.a  program not a bunch of snippets that we have to assemble to even attempt to reproduced the issue.  The other tool you want to know is valgrind.

Comment: You can also use `valgrind --leak-check=full ./my_file_name` and this will tell you where your memory leak is coming from I use it all the time. Just make sure to compile your code with the `-g` option to add debugging symbols. And if you really want, you can add `--track-origins=yes` if you have uninitialized values